# How to perform a Native query on a table which is not present as a class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, nativequery

I have two Tables in my Application - `Resident` and `Vehicle`, which look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resident")
public class Resident {

    @Id                     // PKey
    private String id;

    private Vehicle primaryVehicle;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles; 

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

    @Id                     // PKey
    private String id;

    private String model;

    ...
}
```

This has caused 3 tables created in my Postgres database:

```
resident
vehicle
resident_vehicles
```

So this extra table `resident_vehicles` has been created automatically, there is no class for that table in my codebase.

I have a complex query which requires me to call this table using native query. A simplified query for example would be:

```
select vehicle_id from vehicle_currencies where vehicle_id = '<some-id>'
```

Please note that this query is a simplified version of what I want to do. My SQL queries are more complex, and most importantly dynamically generated at runtime. Using jpa repository methods are very difficult with the dynamic behaviour I have.

I am using Java's Native query for my purpose, like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select vehicle_id from vehicle_currencies where vehicle_id = '<some-id>'

List result = query.getResultList();
...
```

However, this is causing the error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: resident_vehicles is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3782) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3671) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
...
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Use `createNativeQuery` instead of `createQuery`, so it would be `Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(`

Comment: Surprisingly, this simple change worked! Many thanks @ArunSudhakaran! Please write this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Are you sure resident <-> vehicle is many to many? In my country, by law, it's one to many, ie vehicles have one owner.

Comment: @Bohemian Interestingly, yeah! We can have joint owners for a vehicle. A major case for this is when a car is financed, the name of the financer is also mentioned in the registration documents, giving them equal rights, that's why Many to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select vehicle_id from vehicle_currencies where vehicle_id = '<some-id>');
```

You are trying to run a `native query` and since you don't have any mapping for the intermediate table this is the only way. But when we want to run a native query we should use the `createNativeQuery` method inside the `EntityManager`.

The `createQuery` method is used for `HQL` queries require mappings for all the specified tables and that's why you got this issue

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: resident_vehicles is not mapped
```

Links you can refer for detailed explanations

1. [JPA's EntityManager createQuery() vs createNamedQuery() vs createNativeQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798493/jpas-entitymanager-createquery-vs-createnamedquery-vs-createnativequery)
2. [Why do we need to create native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288416/why-do-we-need-to-create-native-query)
3. [use of entityManager.createNativeQuery(query,foo.class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110809/use-of-entitymanager-createnativequeryquery-foo-class)